# Keycloak upgrade while running on docker

Tags: docker, database-migration, keycloak

I'm planning to run my keycloak instance using docker (http://blog.keycloak.org/2015/04/running-keycloak-cluster-with-docker.html) with simplest possible stack

1. Docker image for keycloak itself, latest tag
2. Mysql image for keycloak db with docker volume attached for persistance

The only question that I can't figure out now is how to upgrade keycloak to latest when they release new version and DB schema needs migration. They provide steps how to do migration (https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-documentation/blob/master/server_admin/topics/MigrationFromOlderVersions.adoc) but I cannot figure out what steps should happen when your keycloak is containerized.

Any advice will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**DB migration**

Keycloak [comes with Liquibase](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/misc/UpdatingDatabaseSchema.md) for managing DB versions. What you have to do to upgrade your keycloak should be:

- Backup your DB content and non-DB content (custom providers, themes,
  and so on).
- Run docker again with a newer keycloak tag. Then, Liquibase will
  detect an older version of the DB and perform the necessary steps in
  order to have it updated. Remember you must provide keycloak with
  some user to grant DB altering permissions.

**Config file migration**

There's no automation for this task. If you haven't altered the configuration files, just run the new image. If you have edited them, you need to prepare them for the new version and run the image.

As I've got keycloak configured to run behind a reverse proxy and that needs to have custom configuration files, I wrote a Dockerfile to have my own keycloak docker image, with my own configuration wrapped:

```
FROM jboss/keycloak-mysql:2.4.0.Final
ADD standalone.xml /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration
ADD standalone-ha.xml /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration
CMD ["-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

**Provider, theme... migration**

If you have implemented custom providers or other kind of things, you'll need to check their compatibility with the new version. Otherwise, you might need to rewrite them.

---

As a rule, using **latest** tag is generally a bad idea for production environments, for any image. There is the risk to have any developer/sysadmin running `docker pull` command and performing the updating process automatically, which I guess is not what you want. Better stick to fixed version numbers and perform updates yourself, having done the backups first.

**See also:**

- [Keycloak docker tags](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/tags/)

Comment: Thanks, XBiker I didn't know about liquibase. Sorry, miss typed about using latest tag, definitely for prod I'm going to use specific version.
If liquibase can detect needed changes in my case updating image version should do the trick since I'll not add any customization for theme/settings (will probably do rolling update of my docker images).